# Copia Formulario antes de envia Post no Html

Tags: php, javascript

Como eu faço para eu pegar o texto desse formulario antes de envia ele via post para outra pagina?

```
<html>
    <div class="content-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="wid-vectormap">
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="lista" id="lista" onkeyup="contar_total(this);" placeholder="CC|MESANO|CVV" class="form-control" rows="9">
                                </textarea>
                                ...
```

Comment: Mas cadê o formulário? A qual texto exatamente você se refere?

Comment: copia o texto que a pessoa digita no input do name="lista"

Comment: Queres dizer no `textarea`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("lista").value`

```html
<textarea id="lista" onblur="alert(document.getElementById('lista').value)">
</textarea>
```

Comment: E como faço para salvar no txt o resultado disso?

Comment: @EvelynCarvalho percebo que é nova na comunidade, para tirar melhor proveito considere fazer um [tour] e visitar a [help]. Abra uma nova questão colocando o maior número de detalhes possíveis e principalmente o código que estar a tentar, boa sorte.